# Scheme: How to check if a function has been called with a same argument

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to implement a function (seen x) which takes a argument x and check if the function has been previously called with the same argument.

For example:
`(begin (seen 5) (seen 10)) => #f`

I don't know how to get the previous called function because the function `seen` only takes one argument.

Comment: The simple answer is “global mutable state”, but I am reluctant to provide that because it’s usually a bad idea. What is this for? An answer about implementing memoization will be different than one implementing some sort of search algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to write a procedure that "remembers" previous invocations. This can't be done without using mutable state, but at least we can encapsulate it inside the procedure (to avoid global state):

```
(define seen
  (let ((already-seen (mutable-set)))
    (lambda (n)
      (cond ((set-member? already-seen n)
             #t)
            (else
             (set-add! already-seen n)
             #f)))))
```

The trick was to define a data structure to save the already seen values *before* actually defining the `lambda`. Because the `lambda` closes over its defining context, it has access to that state, and mutate it if necessary.

We can store the already seen values in any data structure that supports a membership test - a list, a hash, you name it. But a `set` is more natural, and that's what I used. The behavior is as expected:

```
(seen 5)
=> #f
(seen 5)
=> #t
(seen 10)
=> #f
```

Comment: Hi, what I get is #procedure , not a boolean value.

Comment: It works for me, maybe you're calling it incorrectly, please post your code. Also, what language are you using? Is it one of the teaching languages?

Comment: I tried again and it works. But I am wondering if there is anyway I can make seen as a function to take an argument?

Comment: This is interesting. Can you add an explanation, why the let expression does not redefine `already-seen` each time `seen` is called? That's the bit I didn't get yet.

Comment: @Zelphir because it was defined _outside_ the `lambda`. The `seen` name was bound to the `lambda` form, but the `already-seen` variable lies in a scope outside of, but still accessible from, that `lambda`. It works because a `lambda` in Scheme is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thank you, the article on wiki is actually written in a quite understandable fashion and I learned something new (or not new, depends on how I look at it) today :) The `let` builds the environment and the function is in that scope so it has access to that environment. The unit of them both is a closure.